# Hive: Execuation error while execuating a query on master node in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-hive

```
hive> select * from twitter_data;
```

1. Query ID =
   hdumer_20160523203816_0c2b2640-f711-41b9-81fd-5ee5d2af900a
       Total jobs = 1
       Launching Job 1 out of 1
       Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
       Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
       2016-05-23 20:38:24,120 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:30,147 Stage-1 map = 2%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:32,164 Stage-1 map = 5%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:35,193 Stage-1 map = 8%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:38,209 Stage-1 map = 11%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:40,218 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:46,242 Stage-1 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:49,253 Stage-1 map = 19%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:52,263 Stage-1 map = 20%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:55,272 Stage-1 map = 22%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:58,291 Stage-1 map = 24%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:38:59,298 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:05,314 Stage-1 map = 30%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:07,320 Stage-1 map = 31%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:29,383 Stage-1 map = 35%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:32,390 Stage-1 map = 38%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:35,398 Stage-1 map = 40%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:38,404 Stage-1 map = 42%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:39,407 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:45,416 Stage-1 map = 49%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:48,423 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:51,430 Stage-1 map = 53%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:54,437 Stage-1 map = 55%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:39:55,438 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:01,450 Stage-1 map = 61%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:04,455 Stage-1 map = 64%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:07,464 Stage-1 map = 66%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:10,472 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:16,482 Stage-1 map = 75%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:19,487 Stage-1 map = 78%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:22,493 Stage-1 map = 79%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:24,498 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
       2016-05-23 20:40:30,520 Stage-1 map = 81%,  reduce = 0%
       Ended Job = job_local348040558_0001 with errors
       Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
       MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
       Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 8822964165 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
       Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

2:Hive Log File;

2016-05-24 22:04:07,489 ERROR [main]: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - Ended Job = job_local932151035_0001 with errors
2016-05-24 22:04:07,507 ERROR [Thread-65]: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
2016-05-24 22:04:07,507 INFO  [Thread-65]: Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1173)) - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2016-05-24 22:04:07,752 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(960)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
2016-05-24 22:04:07,752 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,752 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,753 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 13499720788 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
2016-05-24 22:04:07,753 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
2016-05-24 22:04:07,753 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,753 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,764 INFO  [main]: exec.ListSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(612)) - 3 finished. closing... 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,764 INFO  [main]: exec.ListSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(634)) - 3 Close done
2016-05-24 22:04:07,765 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - 
2016-05-24 22:04:07,765 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) -

could anyone help me to sort out this problem :) thanks in advance

Comment: Congratulations! This is a nice log. Do you have any question? Such as, *"that was local mode (mock-up of a real distributed MapReduce job), so how do I find the local log file that contains the detailed error message, e.g. as OutOfMemory"*?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter is this log is not enough to understand the problem ???

Comment: That's still a Hive log, not a MapReduce log for that `job_local932151035_0001` job -- with the raw Java Exception and stack trace inside.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i have now attached log file of hive as well kindly review it and  help me to sort this problem :)

Comment: Logs from the job traker for map reduce jobs that have failed wiil be more helpful

Comment: @tyagi, look closely at the Hive logs: that session runs in *local mode*, it just *simulates* MapReduce without accessing ResourceManager or JobTracker/HistoryServer... so the pseudo-MR logs have to be somewhere in `/tmp/hive` or `/tmp/<user>` depending on the defaults of that version.

Comment: @tyagi hi okay i have now attached hive log file you can download it from this [https://www.dropbox.com/s/rj0kmubarpe8ejj/hive.log?dl=0]  link and review it i am waiting for your response  and valuable feedback thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter hi okay i have now attached hive log file you can download it from this [dropbox.com/s/rj0kmubarpe8ejj/hive.log?dl=0] link and review it i am waiting for your response and valuable feedback thanks in advance. :)